# Insert comma (INR value) in numeric values - Perl

Tags: perl

I am trying to write a script to make a integer into comma separated value:

> For Example Input : `23454546.3435353 test 123454546789.3435353` #'n' number of values will be present.
>
> I am receiving output: `234, 54, 546.34, 35, 353 test 123454546789.34, 35, 353`
>
> My Query is, after the decimal value do not insert `,`.
>
> Required Output   : `2,34,54,546.**3435353**` test `1,23,45,45,46,789.**3435353**`

My Code:

```
my $strg = "23454546.3435353 test 123454546789.3435353"

$strg=~s#([^\.])(\d{4,})#  my $no_dot=$1; my $nums = $2; my $cnt = $nums=~s/\d/$&/g; 
if($cnt eq 8) {  $nums=~s/^(\d{1})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{3})$/$1\, $2\, $3\, $4/g;  }
if($cnt eq 7) {  $nums=~s/^(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{3})$/$1\, $2\, $3/g;  }
if($cnt eq 6) {  $nums=~s/^(\d{1})(\d{2})(\d{3})$/$1\, $2\, $3/g;  }
if($cnt eq 5) {  $nums=~s/^(\d{2})(\d{3})$/$1\, $2/g;  }
if($cnt eq 4) {  $nums=~s/^(\d{1})(\d{3})$/$1\, $2/g;  }
($no_dot.$nums);
#ge;
```

Please advice where I am doing wrong.

Comment: *"Required Output : 2,34,54,546.**3435353**": Why not 23,45,45,46.3435353? Please explain the algorithm used to insert commas

Comment: Its INR - Indian currency values

Comment: Can you fix the code so that it runs and produces some output please. There is a missing semicolon on the first line. Fixing that produces a script that doesn't output anything. I assume the result is the contents of $strg?

Comment: @ssr1012 *"Its INR"* ok.. so like decribed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system)? I.e.: *".. the Indian numbering system groups the rightmost three digits together (until the hundreds place), and thereafter groups by sets of two digits.."*

Comment: See also [Locale::Currency::Format](https://metacpan.org/pod/Locale::Currency::Format)

Comment: @HåkonHægland:`1 lakh crore, written as 10,00,00,00,00,000`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Perl printf to use commas as thousands-separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33442240/perl-printf-to-use-commas-as-thousands-separator)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe easier to use [Locale::Currency::Format](https://metacpan.org/pod/Locale::Currency::Format) ?

```
use Locale::Currency::Format;
my $inr = currency_format('INR', 23454546.3435353);
say $inr;
```

**Output**:

```
23,454,546.34 INR
```

**Edit**:

It seems like the precision cannot be modified by the module. If you want a precision other than 2, you can try use the brute force approach. For example:

```
my $strg = "23454546.3435353 test 123454546789.3435353";
$strg =~ s/(\d+)\.(\d+)/do_subst($1,$2)/ge;
sub do_subst {
    my ($p1, $p2) = @_;
    my $temp = reverse $p1;
    my @parts;
    push @parts, $1 if $temp =~ s/^(\d{1,3})//;
    while (length $temp) {
        push @parts, $1, if $temp =~ s/^(\d{1,2})//;
    }
    return (join ',', map {my $p = reverse $_; $p} reverse @parts) . '.' . $p2;
}
say $strg;
```

**Output**:

```
2,34,54,546.3435353 test 1,23,45,45,46,789.3435353
```

Comment: Fine. But I need the actual value after the decimal `.3435353` instead of `.34`

Comment: Also, you could just call format with the prefix: `s/(\d+\.\d{1,2})(\d*)/currency_format('INR',$1).$2/ge;`

Comment: @jhnc Yes I thought about that but `currency_format()` did not give correct output see above. It gave `23,454,546` when the expected was `2,34,54,546`

Comment: Didn't spot that. Seems a rather large bug!

Answer (score 1):

Your detection of relevant strings is flawed. You have:

```
([^\.])(\d{4,})
```

but this means the first character can be a digit.
That explains why you get `234,` in your output.
It will also match the digits *one beyond* a period (so in `.3435353`, you match `3435353`). Note that the `\` is not needed (`.` is not special inside square brackets).

Try this:

```perl
$strg =~ s{
    (                # $1:
        ( ^ | \s )   #   delimiter (whitespace or line start)
        \d{4,}       #   digits that need commas
    )
    (?=              # lookahead:
        ( \. \d+ )?  #   optional fractional part
        ( \s | $ )   #   delimiter (whitespace or line end)
    )
}{
    local $_ = $1;
    s/(\d)(?=(\d{2})*\d{3}$)/$1,/g;
    $_;
}xeg;
```

The outer regex matches  runs of 4 or more digits (optionally followed by a fractional part), delimited either by whitespace or at the start/end of the string.

The inner regex also makes use of lookahead to find digits that need commas (ie. 2n+4 from the right). Because of greedy matching of the lookahead, replacements are made starting from the left.

Comment: nice explanations Sr.